# How to reference a map name for a subquery in an HQL order by clause

Tags: sql, hibernate, reference, hql, subquery

I've got an HQL statement like this:

```
select new map (f1 as field1, (select ...) as field2)
from ...
where ...
order by field2;
```

It fails saying "Unknown column 'field2'". I experienced this in general that when using the "new map" statement, I can't reference the map names in the order by field.

As HQL subqueries are only allowed in the select or the where clause, I can't just copy over the subquery to the order by clause either (which wouldn't be so nice anyway).

Am I missing something or do I have to refrain from using a map?

Comment: Interesting question. Never faced this case, but I'm tempted to consider this as a bug.

Comment: You're right - see my answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it, it's really a bug (unresolved since five years!) and it doesn't matter whether I use the alias within "new map" or in the conventional way. However there's a workaround that works for me: Just reference the column using `col_0_0_`, `col_1_0_` etc. This also works with "new map".

See [this bug description](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-892) for more information.